# Kendo Grid Filter Pass in the field

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have:

```
{
                headerTemplate: 'Email invoices',
                field: 'email_invoices',
                filterable: {
                    ui: gridFunctions.yesNoFilterUI.bind(activeGrid),
                    extra: false
                }
            },
```

The filter UI is defined with:

```
define(['jquery', 'kendo', 'util/addMenu', 'config'], function ($, kendo, addMenu, config) {
var obj = {
...
yesNoFilterUI: function (e) {
            var that = this;
            e.kendoDropDownList({
                dataSource: [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "text": "Yes"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "0",
                        "text": "No"
                    }
                ],
                optionLabel: "Select yes/no",
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "id",
                change: function (e) {
                    obj.setInternalFilter(that, 'yesNo', 'eq', this.value());
                }
            });
        },
...
}
return obj;
})
```

The column filter `'yesNo'` is wrong, this needs to be a variable containing the field name i.e. email_invoices.

How can I get or pass this in along the lines of:

```
obj.setInternalFilter(that, field, 'eq', this.value());
```

?

Comment: why can't you set `field` outside the `change` event just as you set the `obj`? Or better, since you init the ddl inside `yesNoFilterUI`, create variable there or pass into it thru argument

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question but, have you tried `obj.setInternalFilter(that, 'yesNo', 'contains', this.value());`

Comment: obj is the object yesNoFilterUI is inside of. The grid and the filter UI are in different files, the filters are brought into the grid file via requirejs as per my edit.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I don't understand what you are saying

Comment: Please see my edit, obj is returned at the end.